# Find Text between special characters and replace string

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

For instance I have a String that contains:

`String s = "test string *67* **Hi**";`

I want to to get this String :

```
*67*
```

With the stars, so I can start replace that part of the string. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
String s = "test string *67* **Hi**";

        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("*") + 1);
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("*"));
```

This outputs: `67` without the stars.

I would like to know how to get a string between some special character, but not with the characters together, like I want to.

The output should be as followed:

```
//output: test string hello **hi**
```

Comment: Careful by replacing a `String` like this. You could replace more than you thought in `"test string *67* **Hi**, I am **67**"`. But since you are already able to find the `String` using `substring`, why not just take the left part, add the replacement part, add the right part.

Comment: @Roadman1991 Would you like to replace also string `*Hi*` ?

Comment: how is this upvoted?...

Comment: Why you want to use replace ??? what you targeting is to separate the string, in this case I would say going with replace is not preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace only the string between special characters :

```
String regex = "(\\s\\*)([^*]+)(\\*\\s)";
String s = "test string *67* **Hi**";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex,"$1hello$3"));

// output: test string *hello* **Hi**
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/xCKjNq) and [Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Co1cYx/3)

**EDIT**
To remove also the special characters use below regex:

```
String regex = "(\\s)(\\*[^*]+\\*)(\\s)";
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/QirDNP)

Comment: I think this is great. But the output should be like this: // output: test string hello **hi**

Comment: Updated the regex to remove also the special characters

Answer (score 2):

You just need to extend boundaries:

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("*"));
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("*", 1)+1);
```

Comment: Like [Mário Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097627/4391450) noted, since you keep the `*` in the first substring, your second `indexOf` will return 0 ;)

Comment: was just going to comment that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("*"));
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("*", 1) + 1);
```

Your +1 is in the wrong place :) Then you just need to find the next one starting from the second position

Answer (score 0):

I think you can even get your output with **List** as well

```
String s = "test string *67* **Hi**";

List<String> sList = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));

System.out.println(sarray.get(sarray.indexOf("*67*")));
```

Hope this will help.